# Hide android web service URL

Tags: android, web-services

when I connect to my server I display it's address in the java code like that :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.13/spotnshare/syncAddress.php");

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

But we told me that having the IP address in the code wasn't correct and that I should put it in a config file as an alias I guess.

Does anyone know about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an element to the app's config file:

```xml
<resources>
  <string name="syncAddress">http://192.168.1.13/spotnshare/syncAddress.php</string>
```

Then set a static string to hold it, and read the config:

```java
public static String SYNCADDRESS = getResources().getString(R.string.syncAddress);
```

Per [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> When your application is compiled, aapt generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory. For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example, R.drawable for all drawable resources) and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example, R.drawable.icon). This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource.

Comment: public static String SYNCADDRESS = R.string.syncAddress;
type of R.string.syncAddress is int, it's doesn't to be work.

Comment: Good catch: I corrected the example code (the resource must be called with getResources().getString()).

Answer (score 0):

create a constant

```
public static final String URL_SYNCADRESS = "your url";
```

then use

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_SYNCADRESS);
```

Comment: just as placing in the resource.

Comment: nope. with it out of the code you can make separate builds using an alternate resource, send the code to someone who doesn't need to know your url, ...

Comment: but it's need get context and then resources.